# How to make CentOS server hung for few minutes on purpose?

Tags: linux, centos

I want reproducing an abnormal behavior of my service, which always arise after the system hang.
Is there any way(better in code) to make the system hung for few minutes on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider `killall -SIGSTOP servicename` and then thawing it with `killall -SIGCONT servicename`?

You could also run your code in a VM and simply suspend it for a while.

Please explain what do you mean by "the system hang" - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want make the hole system unresponsive for few minutes

Comment: @Mark3K  You could run your code in a VM and simply suspend it for a while.

Comment: Considering you're debugging a particular daemon, SIGSTOP'ing it will make it feel like the system has frozen for a while.

Comment: I tried to send SIGTOP to the daemon, but it can't reproducing the abnormal behavior.